# Does EF 6 require a foreign key to have a name that reflects the name of the foreign table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We're working with EF 6's Code First with Existing Database. We're working with SQL Server My boss creates the tables using SQL scripts generated from TOAD. Normally tables are created following this pattern:

- Table name: e.g.: Person
- Primary key: ID (it is *ALWAYS* just ID)

And normally when creating a table that has a 1-to-1 or 1-or-zero relationship with another table it is created using this pattern:

- Table name: Address
- Primary key: ID
- Foreign key to Person: PersonID

However, my boss broke his pattern with two tables and it's causing me a lot of grief. I'm thinking that it is because he named the foreign key something that doesn't follow the pattern, he's used everywhere else. But I could be wrong. Certainly, it doesn't appear to me that EF's code first with existing database recognizes the relationship. Here's a snippet of the SQL for the two tables that are causing problems (I'm removing columns that aren't relevant):

```sql
CREATE TABLE [app].[PersonnelCertification]
(
 [ID] Bigint IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 [CertificationTypeID] Bigint NOT NULL,
 [InstrumentModelID] Bigint NOT NULL,
 [PersonID] Bigint NOT NULL,
 [AgencyID] Bigint NOT NULL,
 [CertificationLevelID] Bigint NOT NULL,
)
```

Here's a SQL snippet to the Proficiency table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [app].[Proficiency]
(
 [ID] Bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [PersonCertID] Bigint NOT NULL,
 [InstrumentID] Bigint NULL,
 [SolutionID] Bigint NOT NULL,
)

ALTER TABLE [app].[Proficiency] ADD CONSTRAINT [PersonnelCertification-Proficiency] FOREIGN KEY ([PersonCertID]) REFERENCES [app].[PersonnelCertification] ([ID]) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
go

ALTER TABLE [app].[Proficiency] ADD CONSTRAINT [Solution-Proficiency] FOREIGN KEY ([SolutionID]) REFERENCES [app].[Solution] ([ID]) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
go

ALTER TABLE [app].[Proficiency] ADD CONSTRAINT [Instrument-Proficiency] FOREIGN KEY ([InstrumentID]) REFERENCES [app].[Instrument] ([ID]) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
go
```

And here's the resultant code generated by code first with existing database, for the Proficiency table:

```cs
[Table("app.Proficiency")]
public partial class Proficiency
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long PersonCertID { get; set; }

    public long? InstrumentID { get; set; }

    public long SolutionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }

    public virtual Solution Solution { get; set; }
}
```

There's a table named *Solution* that's related to Proficiency. There's a table named *Instrument* related to Proficiency. There is nothing in the generated Proficiency model class related to PersonnelCertification. And like I said there's no table named *PersonCert*.

I don't know how to resolve this problem. I've tried adding a `[ForeignKey]` attribute to PersonCertID, but that didn't work. I also tried to add some code in the DbContext generated class for defining a relationship between the two tables that code first with existing databases doesn't recognize, but I couldn't discover what would work. I would appreciate knowing whether or not EF 6 uses something like convention over configuration to determine the foreign key relationships. Such as, would it be better that PersonCertID be renamed to PersonnelCertificationID? Or is there a way of specifying the Fuild API in the DbContext to declare that relationship between Proficiency and PersonnelCertification?

Comment: The name of a database side foreign key has no bearing on how EF relates entities

Comment: Why not just get your boss to follow the pattern used everywhere else, so you can copypasteadjust the EF code pattern you use everywhere else? Or better still get the boss to butt out of software dev and focus on their role (product owner, business development, whatever - they give the feature specs they need and leave the implementation to the engineers)

Comment: are you using Code First or the EF Designer?

Comment: You need a lot of words to tell that you don't know how to map relationships in EF when the naming conventions don't do it for you. It's all well documented, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships.

Comment: Can you update the question with a complete set of DDL that reproduces the issue?  AFAIK this should work fine.  But as @GertArnold points out, you can always just write the classes and map them to the tables by hand.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am the person applying Code First. Thank you, Gert Arnold for the link!! You're right, I don't know the correct term to you (Fluent in this case). Now that I've got a term I can search on, I believe it will go faster for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully somewhere you'll have a `class PersonnelCertification` so you can change your Proficiency like:

```
Table("app.Proficiency")]
public partial class Proficiency
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PersonnelCertification))]
    public long PersonCertID { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonnelCertification PersonnelCertification { get; set; }

    public long? InstrumentID { get; set; }
```

Or you could change it:

```
public partial class Proficiency
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    
    public long PersonCertID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PersonCertID))]
    public virtual PersonnelCertification PersonnelCertification { get; set; }

    public long? InstrumentID { get; set; }
```

Or you can change PersonnelCertification:

```
class PersonnelCertification{

    ...
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Proficiency.PersonCertID))]
    public ICollection<Proficiency> Proficiencies
```

Use whichever appeals to your sense of tying these things together the most. I like option 2

Note, nameof is turned into a string by the compiler; it takes a C# "thing" (class, method, property etc) or "path to a thing" and gives the string Name of the thing. It is useful because it means intellisense helps you write the thing, and if you ever rename via the built in refactoring tools then it will update where a string won't